# Unknown column 'jay' in 'field list'

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to insert values id(Not Auto Incr), Eid, Ename, Esalary, Eaddress from mysql table named employee but following exception is showed

java.sql.SQLException: Unknown column 'jay' in 'field list'

**1. Insert.jsp**

```html
<form method="post" action="Insertbackend.jsp">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:20px ">Enter Employee ID: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="id" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:20px ">Enter Employee Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="En" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:20px ">Enter Employee Salary: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Es" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:20px ">Enter Employee Address: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Ea" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-right:0em;"></td>
            <td style="border-left:0em;"><input type="submit" value="Insert"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

**2. Insetbackend.jsp**

```
<%
try
{
String eid=(String)request.getParameter("id");
String en=(String)request.getParameter("En");
String es=(String)request.getParameter("Es");
String ea=(String)request.getParameter("Ea");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");
Statement s=c.createStatement();

s.executeUpdate("insert into employee values("+eid+","+en+","+es+","+ea+")");
c.close();
s.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    out.println(e);
}

%>
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and avoid using scriptlets at all. Also, use `PreparedStatement` rather than plain `Statement`, since your issue is that you're not using `'` to add the data in your query.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me guided to right way

Answer (score 0):

Edit this line:

```
s.executeUpdate("insert into employee values("+eid+","+en+","+es+","+ea+")");
```

in to:

```
s.executeUpdate("insert into employee values('"+eid+"','"+en+"','"+es+"','"+ea+"')");
```

Since you are using all strings, you must add the quotes surrounded..

Comment: Technically, this may solve the issue. But the real solution is to use `PreparedStatement`s to avoid these headaches.

Comment: Yes @LuiggiMendoza, correct, I just wanted to point out the issue he has.